# Recursive BBCode Parsing

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to parse BBCode in my script. Now, it works seamelessly, until I try to indent BBCode that's more than just bold or underline - such as spoiler, url, font size, etc. - then it screws up. Here's my code:

```
function parse_bbcode($text) {
    global $db;
    $oldtext = $text;
    $bbcodes = $db->select('*', 'bbcodes');
    foreach ($bbcodes as $bbcode) {
        switch ($bbcode->type) {
            case 'simple': {
                $find = '{content}';
                $replace = '${1}';
                $text = preg_replace(
                    '/\['.$bbcode->tag.'\](.+)\[\/'.$bbcode->tag.'\]/i',
                    str_replace($find, $replace, $bbcode->html),
                    $text);
                    break;
            }
            case 'property':
            case 'options': {
                $find = array ( '{property}', '{content}' );
                $replace = array ( '${1}', '${2}' );
                $text = preg_replace(
                    '/\['.$bbcode->tag.'\=(.[^\"]*)\](.+)\[\/'.$bbcode->tag.'\]/i',
                    str_replace($find, $replace, $bbcode->html),
                    $text);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Now my guess is that the RegEx doesn't like the recursiveness in the pattern. How can I improve it? A sample $bbcode object is as such:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '2',
   'name' => 'Italic',
   'type' => 'simple',
   'tag' => 'i',
   'button_image' => NULL,
   'button_text' => '<i>I</i>',
   'options' => '',
   'prompt' => NULL,
   'html' => '<i>{content}</i>',
   'order' => '1',
))
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '3',
   'name' => 'URL',
   'type' => 'property',
   'tag' => 'url',
   'button_image' => NULL,
   'button_text' => 'http://',
   'options' => '',
   'prompt' => 'URL address',
   'html' => '<a href="{property}">{content}</a>',
   'order' => '4',
))
```

Comment: [PHP has a BBCode parser, so no reason to reinvent the wheel](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)

Comment: No shit. I didn't know that. How about making this an answer so I can mark it

Comment: I added a few links to Clement's answer below. Feel free to accept that instead :)

Comment: For anyone looking, I'd like to add the library I wrote that is currently the best of those I was able to find: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As gordon said in comments [PHP has a BBCode parser, so no reason to reinvent the wheel](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php).

The native parser is a PECL package though, so you will have to install it. If that's not an option (for instance due to shared hosting), there is also a PEAR package: http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser

In addition to those, you can take a look at forums using BB code source code, and either use their parser, or improve it. There is also several PHP implementations listed at http://www.bbcode.org/implementations.php

Comment: The PECL package seems awesome, but I can't install it... The PEAR one is lame :/

Answer (score 0):

Correctly parsing BBcode using regex is non-trival. The codes may be nested. `CODE` tags may contain BBCodes which must be ignored by the parser. Certain tags may not appear inside of other tags. etc. However, it can be done. I recently overhauled the BBCode parser for the FluxBB open source forum software. You may want to check it out in action:

[New 2011 FluxBB Parser](http://web.archive.org/web/20110322173538/http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/fluxbb_jmr_dev/)

Note that this new parser has not yet been incorporated into the FluxBB codebase.

Comment: Is this fully operational? And how easily can I add my own BBCode?

Comment: Yes it is operational (the link above is a test forum which uses this parser). This is not a generic parser - Its designed specifically to work with FluxBB. You'll need to read the [documentation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/fluxbb_jmr_dev/viewforum.php?id=1) and the [source code](https://github.com/jmrware/fluxbb_jmr_dev/blob/dev/include/parser.php). I assume you are a PHP programmer and are familiar with [regular expressions](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/fluxbb_jmr_dev/viewtopic.php?id=3). As I said, parsing BBCode is non-trivial.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with PHP and RegEx (see question), but BBCode is simple enough to parse -- until it gets recursive

Comment: @OhMrBigshot: The complexity of the problem is not limited to just recursion but in how the tags nest inside each other. e.g. Will you allow a `URL` tag inside an `IMG` tag? Or how about allowing a `QUOTE` tag inside an `I` tag? You need to set up a system of rules (which parallel HTML) that define what is allowed to nest inside each tag. Also, there needs to be rules for allowable parent tags, e.g. A `LI` (or `*`) tag may only appear inside a `LIST` tag.